# How do lambda parameters work?

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say we have a class Student

```
class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public List<string> Subjects { get; set; }

    public static List<Student> GetAllStudetns()
    {
        List<Student> listStudents = new List<Student>
        {
           new Student
           {
               Name = "Tom",
               Gender = "Male",
               Subjects = new List<string> { "ASP.NET", "C#" }
           },
           new Student
           {
              Name = "Mike",
               Gender = "Male",
               Subjects = new List<string> { "ADO.NET", "C#", "AJAX" }
           }
        };

        return listStudents;
    }
}
```

And we want to print out each student with subjects like this:

> Tom - ASP.NET
>
> Tom - C#
>
> Mike - ADO.NET
>
> Mike - C#
>
> etc

so the answer I found is

```
var result = Student.GetAllStudents().SelectMany(s => s.Subjects, (student, subject) => new { StudentName = student.Name, SubjectName = subject});

//then use foreach loop to retrieve...
```

I can understand the second use of =>, which is just projection to a anonymous type. But I don't understand the first part

```
s => s.Subjects, (student, subject)
```

From my understanding, the left side of => is intput parameter which is Student instance s in this case, but the right side of => should be return type related to the Student instance s,for example, s.Name if we want to get the student's name, so what does (student, subject) mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SelectMany is overloaded.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631(v=vs.110).aspx

`s => s.Subjects` is your collection selector - the transform that will be applied to each element of the input

and `(student, subject) => new { StudentName = student.Name, SubjectName = subject}` is your result selector - the transform function to apply to each element of the intermediate sequence

Comment: Thank you. Now I see. I should see the comma , as a separator

Comment: Please add something about how `s => Subjects` and `(...) => ...` are different things, and it's not `s => s.Subjects, (...)`

Answer (score 1):

It is because `Subjects` is defined as a `List<string>` inside the class and you have to print it as separately, So it needs to iterate over the collection of the sub-list. Before explaining the requested part(`s => s.Subjects, (student, subject)`) of the query, you should take a look into the definition of the `.SelectMany`

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>> selector
)
```

As per the signature of the method, the second parameter(`Func`) is accepting the source object(here it is of type `Student`) and an `IEnumerable` collection objects, here that is of type string, since that is a `List<string>`.

Which means student in `(student, subject)` is of type `Student` and subject will be an item in `s.Subjects`, So the `.SelectMany` will further iterates through the sub collection here.

If you want to print like this(`Tom - ASP.NET,C#`) means you can do `GroupBy` in your case You don't want to go for that so performs iteration over the sub-list using that code;

Additional information: If the result is based on grouping then your code will be like this:

```
var result = Student.GetAllStudents()
                    .GroupBy(s => s.Name)
                    .Select(x=> new { StudentName = x.Key, SubjectName = String.Join(",",
                   x.SelectMany(y=>y.Subjects)
                    .ToList()});
```

Comment: So what's (student, subject)?  is it a combination parameter?

Comment: Are you answering the question that was asked?